# How to read binary avro fileData, with Source in akka?

Tags: scala, io, akka, avro, akka-stream

I'm trying to read an avro file with Source from akka Streams.

Source in akka streams read data like FileIO.FromPath(File), which will read and separate the lines based on (\n) character, where as for avro how does it work?

Flow :

```
    object AvroFlow  {
    def apply(jobDate: String): Flow[GenericRecord, GenericRecord, NotUsed] = {
            Flow[GenericRecord].map { rec => rec.put("date", "20190812") rec}       
    }
  }
```

Graph:

```
object AvroRunner {
    def build (src: Source[GenericRecord, NotUsed],
                                     flw: Flow[GenericRecord, GenericRecord, NotUsed],
                                     snk:Flow[GenericRecord, Future[Done])
    : AvroRunner = {
      new AvroRunner(srtc,flw,snk)
    }
  }
class AvroRunner private(src: Source[GenericRecord, NotUsed],
                                     flw: Flow[GenericRecord, GenericRecord, NotUsed],
                                     snk:Flow[GenericRecord, Future[Done]){
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  val GraphRunner = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() {implicit builder =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._
    src ~> flw ~> snk
    ClosedShape
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to create an akka `Source` of avro data objects wouldn't be from the raw binary file itself.  Rather, create the Source from the `DataFileReader` provided by the avro library.

From [the documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/gettingstartedjava.html#Deserializing) we first create the file reader from a `java.io.File` generator:

```
def createFileReader[T : ClassTag](fileGenerator : () => File) : DataFileReader[T] = 
  new DataFileReader[T](file(), new SpecificDatumReader[T](classTag[T].runtimeClass))
```

This can then be used to create a scala `Iterator`:

```
def dataFileReaderToIterator[T](dataFileReader : DataFileReader[T]) : Iterator[T] = 
  new Iterator[T] {
    override def hasNext : Boolean = dataFileReader.hasNext

    override def next() : T = dataFileReader.next
  }
```

We can now construct a stream Source from the file generator:

```
def fileToAvroSource[T](fileGenerator : () => File) : Source[T, _] = 
  Source.fromIterator[T](() => dataFileReaderToIterator[T](createFileReader(fileGenerator)))
```

**Backpressure?**

It appears that avro is using standard BufferedReader/OutputStream techniques to read the `File`.  Therefore, the above implementation should provide backpressure all the way to the source of the File.  However, I have not confirmed this to be the case...

Comment: Hi Ramon, Thanks for the reply. I created the Source fromIterator() , but when i connected the Source to the Flow[GenericRecord,GenericRecord,_], Flow is not getting any records. But in Source i was able to print the records.Anything that i'm missing over here...  Eg: Flow[GenericRecord].map { x.put(dt,"20190624")}

Comment: @Aravinda You are welcome.  I would have to see your `Flow` code, and stream code, to be able to debug...

Comment: @J Romero Vigil,I have included the code in above tag along with question. Is there anything that i'm missing.